# How to diagnose display issues in linux?

Tags: debian, drivers, graphics, display

I have recently upgraded my system to Debian Jessie (testing) and everything went smoothly, except the occasional distortion when the screen is updating.

When a part of the screen needs to update, lines across the screen appear for several seconds, as if there is some kind of interference. I am using open source driver (for amd 4570) and would really like to get
to the bottom of the issue myself, however I am stuck as to what I can actually do next:

Things I have done:

1- rebooted from a live cd to check that the screen and graphics card aren't faulty- all good here, no flicker.
2- changed desktop environments, to rule out some sort of bug. It occurs much less often on XFCE, but it is not eliminated.

3- Updated the system to the latest and installed the latest available kernel (3.16). NO change.

Apart from reinstalling everything from scratch, is there something that I can do?

/var/log/messages, dmesg and kern.long dont indicate any obvious failures.

System is definitely not overheating.